# Weird problem with connection from putty to ubuntu server via SSH

Tags: ubuntu, putty

I have an Ubuntu Server 9.10 box with `sshd` configured. I have two computers with Windows 7 professional and putty installed. Day ago, both computers was able to connect ubuntu server both via putty and plink. I have installed `sun-java6-jre` on ubuntu server, and now have a weird problem. First Windows 7 computer can still connect with both putty GUI and command-line `plink`. Second computer can connect via putty gui, but if i issue `plink` command that works perfectly on first computer:

```
plink www.hostname.tk -i c:\users\username\documents\key\private.ppk
```

I get `login` prompt, enter same username as on first computer, and receive following weird error message:

```
bash: www.hostname.tk: command not found
```

I can't see any difference between my Windows 7 computers :(. The `ppk` key used is same (i copied it multiple times both ways). `hostname` and `username` are same. Anyone have any ideas why such thing happens and what can i do in order to troubleshoot and fix it?

Updated:

Log that `plink -v` disaplys:

```
Offered public key
Offer of public key accepted
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Started a shell/command
bash: www.hostname.tk: command not found
Server sent command exit status 127
Disconnected: All channels closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running `plink -v` and post that output?. Below I've changed the command to echo $PATH:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\dave>plink 10.0.1.1 -v /bin/echo $PATH
Looking up host "10.0.1.1"
Connecting to 10.0.1.1 port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-6ubuntu2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.60
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 4a:84:5d:a8:a2:29:95:c0:4e:92:d1:38:68:e6:2b:5f
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
login as: dmo
dmo@10.0.1.1's password:
Sent password
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Started a shell/command
Server sent command exit status 0
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
Disconnected: All channels closed
```

Comment: After login my log looks like this:

    Offered public key

    Offer of public key accepted

    Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"

    Access granted

    Opened channel for session

    Started a shell/command

    bash: www.hostname.tk: command not found

    Server sent command exit status 127

    Disconnected: All channels closed

Comment: Added plink log to original question.

Comment: Same error, but in verbose log 'bash: www.hostname.tk: command not found' now goes AFTER 'Server sent command exit status 127' O_O. This SSH eats my brain :(.

Comment: I have found it. As always, "what have you done to your computer?" "Nothing!" "OMG, never do 'nothing' at your computer, it messes things up!". I just remembered that on a problem computer i have saved session in putty GUI to 'default'. And somehow this is messed up plink! After clearing 'hostname' for 'default' in putty GUI, all is working fine again O_O.

Answer (score 1):

well seeing as PC 1 Can connect using both its fair to say your server is still yp and running and isn't acting quirky.

If I was you I'd go digging on PC 2 see whats different from PC 1. New firewall updates, different firewall software ?

Comment: No changes at all :(. I have updates configured to 'manual', no installs for last week.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that something in `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc` is mistakenly executing `$HOSTNAME` as a command or the result of `` `hostname` `` or `$(hostname)`. Look for one of those on a line by itself (or inside (an extra set of) backticks or `$()`). If this is the case, I have no idea why it would be this way on one client computer and not the other or what it would have to do with your installing Java.

Comment: I have carefullt checked specified files. No sign of `hostnamez`. Maybe it's possible to somehow log this issue?

Comment: "...something in [list of files] is mistakenly executing..." or a file they call or source (ad infinitum) or `/etc/ssh/sshrc` or `~/.ssh/rc`.